# How to put the selected item into the input box through js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello everyone~ I am a beginner in programming and my English is not very good. I will try my best to describe my problem!

I currently want to implement a function

1. Click the input box to pop up a window
2. Select some options in the window
3. The selected options can be put into this input box...
4. Options can be checked

But I am in the step of selecting options and putting into the input box. When it's difficult, I don't know how to achieve it!
So it would be better to ask you how to do this part?

thank you all!

```js
$(function(){
  $('.input_box').on('click',function(){
    $('.sport').css('display','block');
  })
})

$(function(){
  $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
})

// Attempt to compose failed

// $(function(){
//   $('.item').on('click',function(e){
//     console.log(e.value);
//   })
// })
```

```css
.input_box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sport {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sport_content {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.sport_content .title {
  text-align: center;
}
.sport_content .category {
  display: flex;
}
.sport_content .category .item {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="">Choose your favorite sport</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in your favorite sports" class="input_box">

<div class="sport">
  <div class="sport_content">
     <h2 class="title">Aerobic exercise</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="跑步">RUN</li>
       <li class="item" value="游泳">Swim</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code.I hope it's fit your needs

```js
$(function(){
  $('.input_box').on('click',function(){
    $('.sport').css('display','block');
  })
})

$(function(){
  $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
})

// Attempt to compose failed

$(function(){
  $('.item').on('click',function(e){
    // only a little change here
    const val = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    $('.input_box').val(val);
    $('.sport').trigger("click");
  })
})
```

```css
.input_box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sport {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sport_content {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.sport_content .title {
  text-align: center;
}
.sport_content .category {
  display: flex;
}
.sport_content .category .item {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="">Choose your favorite sport</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in your favorite sports" class="input_box">

<div class="sport">
  <div class="sport_content">
     <h2 class="title">Aerobic exercise</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="跑步">RUN</li>
       <li class="item" value="游泳">Swim</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for telling me about this and the method~
But because I am a beginner, I have a question to ask~

If today I hope that the items in the window can be multi-selected instead of single-selected, how should I rewrite it?

Comment: simple way to achieve multi-select change `$('.input_box').val(val);` to `$('.input_box').val(val+$('.input_box').val());`.if you want user finish multi-select in single popup,that need more css and js

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.input_box').on('click',function(){
            $('.sport').css('display','block');
        });
        $('.sport').click(function(e){
            if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
                $(this).css('display','none');
            }
        })
        $('ul.category > li').on('click',function (){
            const value = $(this).attr('data-value');
            $('#input').val(value);


        })
    })
```

```css
 .input_box {
        width: 500px;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .sport {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .sport_content {
        width: 500px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .sport_content .title {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sport_content .category {
        display: flex;
    }
    .sport_content .category .item {
        width: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    ul li{
        cursor: pointer;

    }
    ul li:first-child{
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label for="">Choose your favorite sport</label><br>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Put in your favorite sports" class="input_box">

<div class="sport">
    <div class="sport_content">
        <h2 class="title">Aerobic exercise</h2>
        <ul class="category">
            <li class="item" data-value="跑步">RUN</li>
            <li class="item" data-value="游泳">Swim</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for telling me about this and the method~
But because I am a beginner, I have a question to ask~

If today I hope that the items in the window can be multi-selected instead of single-selected, how should I rewrite it?